# Probability Disribution Tables

Tags: probability, statistics

For the following problem, do I have 9 outcomes or 20? And how do I set up this distribution table (is there a side for students and one for parents?)

Determine the probability distribution, in table form and graphical form, for the number of students selected to be in a six-person fund-raising committee from 9 students and 11 teachers.

Answer (score 1):

You have neither 9 nor 20 outcomes, but 7.

The 7 possible outcomes are having 0,1,2,3,4,5, or 6 students in the committee.

Now, if you have 0 students, you need 6 teachers. Also, there are $9\choose0$ ways to pick 0 students out of 9, and $11\choose6$ ways to pick 6 teachers out of 11. So, there are ${9\choose0}{11\choose6}$ possible committees with 0 students.

Likewise, you get ${9\choose1}{11\choose5}$ committees with 1 student, etc.

Finally, to compute probabilities, we divide each of those numbers by the nuber of all possible committees, which is $20\choose6$. Of course, that is assuming we pick each of the 20 people with equal probability to be on th committee.

Comment: So youre saying on the left column of my table I should go down from 0 to 6, and with the right side would I do 7c0 , 7c1 , and etc?

Comment: @K.A No. For $x$ in $\{0, 1, 2,3,4,5,6\}$, the probability for selecting $x$ from $9$ students and $6-x$ from $11$ teachers when selecting $6$ from $20$ people is:....

Comment: @K.A Yes, though you also need to choose the appropriate number of teachers to get a full committee of 6 members. So, with 0 students, you get 7C0 * 11C6 possible committees, with 1 student you get 7C1 * 11C5, etc.

Comment: @Bram28 There are 9 students from which to select.

Comment: Wait, sorry, but are you sure this is correct? Since it is the probability shouldnt I be dividing and getting a percent?

Comment: Should I be dividing all the x numbers with 7 or 20?

Comment: @GrahamKemp Quite!  I got confused myself ... :(

Comment: @K.A I updated my answer ...

Comment: @Bram28 thank you so so so much!! I swear I did not understand these distributions at all until now!

Comment: @K.A You're welcome!